# Moving mean square error between 2 arrays, 'valid', where they fully overlap

Tags: python, numpy

You can find my original post [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63502080/moving-mean-square-error-between-2-arrays-valid-where-they-fully-overlap/63502297?noredirect=1#comment112291823_63502297). I was very surprised that I couldn't find a pre-coded function doing a mean square error between a signal (array A, size a) and a pattern (array B, size b<a) in a sliding window fashion. Thus I made one... and obviously it needs a lot of code improvement. I don't really know how to vectorize the implementation.

The goal is to take the pattern, slide it across the signal one step at a time, and determine everytime the mean square error between the signal and the pattern.

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import numpy as np

def correlate_edge_pattern(signal, pattern):
    
    ms_errors = list()
    k=0
    
    while True:
        
        data = signal[k:k+pattern.size]
        
        if data.size != pattern.size:
            break
        
        err = mean_squared_error(pattern, data)
        ms_errors.append(err)
        k+=1
    
    m = np.argmin(ms_errors)
    
    return m
```

As you can observe below, it works as expected:

[image: correlated pattern]

Here is a small code sample to test it:

```
signal = -np.ones(1000)*20
signal[:100] = 0
signal[900:] = 0
noise = np.random.normal(0,1,size=1000)
noisy_signal = signal + noise

pattern = np.zeros(50)
pattern[:25] = -20
```